# XPath logical AND for 2 buttons existence within same DIV

Tags: xpath, selenium, logical-operators

I have an XPath expression which validates Boolean True correctly with the following:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'toolbar')]//div[starts-with(@id, 'button')]//a/span[text() = 'Update'] and //div[starts-with(@id, 'toolbar')]//div[starts-with(@id, 'button')]//a/span[text() = 'Save']
```

That is fine, but it does not assert whether both elements are contained within the same DIV, which is what I am trying to use in a Selenium script.

If `//div[starts-with(@id, 'toolbar')]` is a matched DIV element, how can I assert that both:

`//div[starts-with(@id, 'button')]//a/span[text() = 'Update']`

and

`//div[starts-with(@id, 'button')]//a/span[text() = 'Save']`

are contained within it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunally no input XML is provided, but I guess this is what you search:

```
 //div[starts-with(@id, 'toolbar') and div[starts-with(@id, 'button')]/a/span[. = 'Update'] and div[starts-with(@id, 'button')]/a/span[. = 'Save']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is able to isolate my target container, but I would prefer an answer which is able to do it using the `DIV > A > SPAN > TEXT` as in the original question:

`//div[starts-with(@id, 'toolbar')][contains(div, 'Update') and contains(div, 'Save')]`

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the XPath you are looking for:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'toolbar') and //div[starts-with(@id, 'button')]//a/span[text() = 'Update'] and //div[starts-with(@id, 'button')]//a/span[text() = 'Save']]
```